# How to create cookie in a Controller method in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.5

How Can I make a cookie in a controller method like User_login::is_logged_in() in laravel ?

And How can I access to it ?

I used following code in my controller but it didn't create any cookie:

```
cookie('wesna_login_cookie', Hash::make($result->login), 2000);
```

Comment: show the code what u have tried so far. show code

Comment: Usually, it requires writing code. Anyhow, I would advise you to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) guide.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get your question but you can check [Laravel Cookies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#cookies)